How does write-ahead logging actually work?
I've read the explanation for write-ahead logging techniques such as that used in SQLite, and every single time I failed to understand it. Every time they say the following.
1 Rollback journal method:
Amass a number of transactions you need to do. When it's time to write into the database copy the contents of the original to a new storage area, sync with disk, write the pending transactions to the database, sync with disk, then delete the copy. Right that makes sense.

Write-ahead log method:

All the transactions are written to a separate WAL file. Then, either manually or automatically it becomes time to sync or checkpoint the transactions with the database, and this is done.
I haven't seen any explanation with regard to how this prevents data inconsistency when you need to "sync"/merge the transactions in the WAL file with the database file. It seems you still need to copy the original contents that are going to be overwritten/modified BEFORE anything is written to the database to a separate rollback journal area anyway. Isn't this the case? Please could someone shed some light on this explaining what takes place so I can understand it better.

If you haven't already, you might want to read either the Wikipedia page or the original paper on ARIES. Because it does describe an algorithm in detail
